# Fechar programa especifico em java(.jar) com C++

Tags: java, c++

Tenho um programa em java rodando, gostaria de fecha-lo caso necessário com um monitor escrito em C++. Como no taskmgr so aparece java.exe, como fechar o programa.jar especifico?

Comment: O comando jps mostra todos os *.jar que estão rodando na JVM  que contem um PID  que você pode dar um kill para aquele *.jar especifico.

Comment: Programas que rodam dentro da JVM tendem a rodar em cima do processo java.exe mesmo, não creio que haja diferenciação, pois quem está rodando, na verdade, é o java e não seu programa em si.

Comment: ok, mas não posso matar o java.exe pois também iria derrubar outros serviços, estou iniciado o .jar pelo system(" start..."), tem como chamar e já pegar o pid nesse momento? obs: usando o windows 10.

Comment: Então no Windows não sei como fazer, pois nunca o fiz. Trabalho com aplicação distribuídas,  cada um com seu jar. As vezes em local tenho que matar somente uma utilizei o JPS pego pid e dou kill as outras aplicações continua rodando

Comment: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SAPMOB/How+to+use+Microsoft++PsTools%28Psexec%29+and+jstack+to+help+trouble+shoot+a+hanging+SUP+Server

Indicado pelo colega de trabalho.